# Troubles connecting microcontroller STM32 NUCLEO-F401RE as a USB device to PC

Tags: microcontroller, usb, wiring, software

This is as much a software question as it is electronics question, but here we go. I am very new to STM32 micro controllers and I've been sitting with this problem for the last 3 days of so

My goal: send a string using `CDC_Transmit_FS(string,sizeof(string));` from a STM32F401RE (NUCLEO Dev board) to PC via Full Speed USB through Virtual Com Port.

Problem: PC does not recognize STM32 as a Full Speed USB device. Fails to enumerate it.

Here is output from `sudo dmesg`:

```
[87338.796874] debugfs: Directory '27' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87338.910843] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 58 using xhci_hcd
[87339.025875] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[87339.243812] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[87339.352913] debugfs: Directory '28' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87339.466841] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd
[87339.581882] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[87339.803879] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[87339.912941] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[87340.224912] debugfs: Directory '29' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87340.540844] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 60 using xhci_hcd
[87340.541475] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[87340.541598] debugfs: Directory '30' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87340.745309] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[87340.745485] debugfs: Directory '22' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87340.952785] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 60, error -71
[87341.066838] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 61 using xhci_hcd
[87341.067472] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[87341.273463] usb 2-2: Device not responding to setup address.
[87341.273584] debugfs: Directory '02' with parent 'devices' already present!
[87341.480837] usb 2-2: device not accepting address 61, error -71
[87341.480949] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Output from `sudo lsusb` and `sudo lsusb -t`:

```
[veta@equis ~]$ sudo lsusb
Password: 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b2ea Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 057: ID 0483:374b STMicroelectronics ST-LINK/V2.1
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[veta@equis ~]$ sudo lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 57, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 57, If 1, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 57, If 2, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 57, If 3, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 2, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 3, Class=Application Specific Interface, Driver=, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 7, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 6: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

Power is fed via the programmer ST-LINK, which is connected to same PC, different USB port.

I have split open a USB cable and soldered header pins to each of the 4 wires inside.

- White (D+) is connected to PA12
- Green (D-) is connected to PA11
- Red (VBUS) is connected to PA9
- Black (GND) is redundant as the MCU is fed from same power source, but I have tried with it connected to one of the GND pins too

I have also tried setting USB into FS mode manually by pulling up D+ USB pin with a 1.5k Ohm resistor:
[image: manual-Dp-pull-up]

and leaving pulling-up to the MCU to handle:
[image: stm32-Dp-pull-up]

In STM32CubeMX my configuration is as follows, everything else is left default:

USB_OTG_FS under Connectivity tab:

- Mode: Device Only
- Activate VBUS: yes
- Avtivate SOF: no

USB_DEVICE under Middleware tab:

- Class for FS IP: Communication Device Class (Virtual Port Com)

RCC under System Core tab:

- High Speed Clock: Crystal/Ceramic Resonator

Clock Configuration is set in such a way, so that 48MHz clocks is set to 48MHz.

If something is unclear, tell me so. It's 2 am and I was working with this for last 15 hours now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB specs say green is D+ and white is D-, but in reality who knows which way they are connecte so better check it. Also just in case you are using a separate ST-Link pod instead of the one that is integrated on the Nucleo, a separate ST-Link device does not output 3.3V so it will not power external devices (it is used as a voltage reference for other wires) but a Nucleo board with embedded ST-Link the USB debug connector should power up the whole board.

Answer (score 2):

> 87339.466841] usb 2-2: new low-speed USB device number 59 using xhci_hcd

This is a direct result of pulling up D- rather than D+.  Even if you had no MCU, just getting that right would change the detection message.

Check your wiring.

Check all your assumptions - for example, it is *not* a safe assumption that on some random cable you cut up, white is D+ and green is D-.  Or for that matter that red and black are what you think *they* are.  There is also at least one website with a picture (quoted here in the past) that shows the D+ and D- lines in the wrong places on a USB connector.

Try connecting only ground and D+ to 3v3 via the resistor - if you are actually pulling up the correct line, you will get a message about detecting a full speed device.  Of course without the MCU and appropriate firmware enumeration will still fail, but *detection* will be correct.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a Godsend! That was it. So much headache and time could have been spared had I not made that assumption